# Remove adjacent duplicate numbers

Tags: python

I followed another post on here to create a function that receives a list of numbers and removes all adjacent duplicate numbers. It is working for all my test cases except the one below. The logic makes sense to me and I'm just not seeing where I'm going wrong. If anyone can help I'd greatly appreciate it.

```
def removeAdjacentNumbers(numList):
    previous = ''
    for i in numList[:]:
        if i == previous:
            numList.remove(i)
        else:
            previous = i
    return numList
    
def main():
    print(removeAdjacentNumbers([2,2,4,4,2,2,5,5]))

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

It is returning:
`[4, 2, 2, 5]`
And is supposed to return:
`[2, 4, 2, 5]`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step. It would be better if you came asking here ***after*** you tried some basic debug and can ask about what specifically you cannot fix. Right now it seems like you're not asking us to debug your code for you...

Comment: `remove` always removes the ***first*** occurrence it encounters. So by the time it reaches the last `2`, it will remove the second one, not the third (which is the adjacent one)

Answer (score 2):

You had a good start. Below is a fix of your code:

```
def removeAdjacentNumbers(numList):
    previous = None
    out = []              # define a new list for output
    for i in numList:     # no need to slice here
        if i != previous: # if we have a new value
            out.append(i) # we save it for output
        previous = i
    return out
```

The major issue was that you remove the first element of the list from the left.

If you really want to use your methods you should use `pop` with the index and not `remove`, and you should iterate over the list backwards to keep consistent index (or keep track of the number of deletion and subtract this to your pop value):

```
def removeAdjacentNumbers(numList):
    previous = ''
    for i, value in enumerate(numList[::-1]):
        if value == previous:
            numList.pop(len(numList)-i-1)
        else:
            previous = value
    return numList
```

Comment: Not precisely, the OP was iterating over `numList[:]` which is a copy of the list

Comment: Yes, right, but anyway, this has unexpected consequences, then enumerate and pop should be used

Comment: No, it is pretty expected. The real problem was that `remove` removes the first occurrence it finds so when reaching the second chink of `2`s it actually removed the first occurrence of it instead of the adjacent one...

Comment: I mean it has unexpected consequences as the method to remove is wrong, one should use pop and iterate over the list backwards, let me add an example

Comment: It is not unexpected if you read the docs... ;) (by *you* I mean the OP, or anyone else *not* reading the docs)

Comment: OK, but then nothing is unexpected unless there is a bug or hardware failure :p

Answer (score 1):

@mozway is correct.
Here is one of the many ways to do it, while altering the list when iterating over it. I just came with this quick approach.

```py
i = 0
numList = [2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 5, 5]

while i < len(numList)-1:
    if numList[i] == numList[i+1]:
        numList.pop(i)
    else:
        i += 1

print(numList)
```

I wonder how the time and space complexities are compared to @mozway's answer.

Comment: sorry, but using a `try/except` to prevent a off-by-one error is really gross :p

Comment: you can just do `while i < len(numList)-1` why on earth are you using try except without even checking specifically for `IndexError`?

Comment: yeah my bad, as i said its the most non-pythonic quick answer came to my mind, and it will be `while i < len(numList) - 1`